# Why did they evacuate the planet?

Tags: extinction

I just finished watching Netflix’s [*Extinction*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3201640/).

Throughout the movie we understand that following a robot riot/resistance humans left Earth.

Doesn’t it seem a little extreme to abandon Earth? The robots don’t seem to be all-powerful beings. They’re not in sync through some hive mind.

Maybe abandon some city, neighborhood... but the entire planet Earth? Humans couldn’t regroup in a different place?

I thought, maybe in this future, Earth is under water or something else and this is the last city, but in the last scene we see Earth seems to be just fine.

Comment: The humans were driven off the Earth by a robot uprising. Staying appears to have been a recipe for genocide.

Comment: On one hand, they would need to be pretty powerful to convince humans to abandon earth, on the other hand, for a group that prepared 50 years for humans to “come back”, their defense was basically zero. That’s what’s bothering me. This contradiction ...

Comment: They should have set it further into the future. Y3K

Comment: @NathanH they might have been preparing for 50years but there wasn't many that knew. likewise they don't seem to be able to innovate.